# Cascading text box is not working correctly in MVC4?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have four fields in my view **CustomerName**, **ContactPerson**, **Email**, **MobileNo**

**CustomerName** and **ContactPerson** are Cascading Dropdown, and Email and MobileNo are textboxes.

If I select the CustomerName, related ContactPerson will load automatically in ContactPerson dropdown.

If I select the **Contactperson** the Contact person related **Email** and **PhoneNo** will load automatically in Email and PhoneNo textbox. This works as expected.

Now all are working fine the two cascading drop down are working fine now my issue is if i select the contact person the contact person related Email and phone no is not displaying in that appropriate text boxes.

**My Controller Code:**

```
public JsonResult GetCustomers()
{
return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult GetContactPersobByCustomerId(string customerId)
{
Guid Id = Guid.Parse(customerId);
var customercontacts = (from a in db.CustomerContacts where a.CustomerID == Id select a);
return Json(customercontacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
} 

public JsonResult GetPhoneNoByContactPersonID(Guid CustomerContactId)
    {
        var resultMobileNumber = string.Empty;
        var resultEmail = string.Empty;
        var ContactID = db.CustomerContacts.Where(i => i.CustomerContactID == CustomerContactId).Select(i => i.ContactID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (ContactID != null)
        {
            var contact = (from p in db.Contacts where p.ContactID == ContactID select p).FirstOrDefault();
            if (contact != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Mobile1) == false)
                {
                    resultMobileNumber = contact.Mobile1;
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Mobile2) == false)
                {
                    resultMobileNumber = contact.Mobile2;
                }
            }
            if (contact != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Email1) == false)
                {
                    resultEmail = contact.Email1;
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Email2) == false)
                {
                    resultEmail = contact.Email2;
                }
            }
        }
        var details = new { success = true, email = resultEmail, mobileno = resultMobileNumber };
        return Json(details, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View Code:**

```
@Html.Label("Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new {     @class = "form-control required", type = "text" })

@Html.Label("Contact Person", new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerContactID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "CustomerContactID" })

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text",disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly"  })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" ,disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
```

**J-query Code**

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function () {
 $.ajax(
'@Url.Action("GetCustomers", "VisitorsForm")',{
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "Json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $('#CustomerID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerID + '">' + value.DisplayName + '</option>');
        });
    }
});

 $('#CustomerID').change(function () {
 $('#CustomerContactID').empty();
 $.ajax(
   '@Url.Action("GetContactPersobByCustomerId", "VisitorsForm")',{
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "Json",
        data: { CustomerID: $('#CustomerID').val() },
        success: function (data) {
    $('#CustomerContactID').append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
         $('#CustomerContactID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerContactID + '">' + value.ContactReference + '</option>');
           });
          }
       });
    });
});

  $("#CustomerContactID").change(function () {
   alert("hhh");
   debugger;
    $.ajax(
        '@Url.Action("GetPhoneNoByContactPersonID", "VisitorsForm")',{
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            data: { CustomerContactID: $("#CustomerContactID").val()
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Email.' + ex);
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {

                $("#Email").val(data.email);
                $("#MobileNo").val(data.mobileno)
                alert("Success");
            }
         });
     });
```

Now all are working fine when i click the contact person it come to the **GetPhoneNoByContactPersonID** action it calculate the values and return again to the view  ans it is also visible in Network too. All are perfect but it not displaying the data in textbox. while i inspect the code it didn't show any  error in console. But it shows one warning message which is mentioned below.

[image: Output in Network]

Now all are working fine. But i donno why it is not displaying i donno where is the issue is.  I tried my level bwst to explain  my issue.-please any one help me to clear this issue.

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no id associated with.So assign an id first in `TextBoxFor` like this.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MobileNo, new {@id = "MobileNo", @class = "form-control", type = "text",disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly"  })

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new {@id = "Email", @class = "form-control", type = "text" ,disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Now this should work

```
$("#Email").val(data.email);
$("#MobileNo").val(data.mobileno)
```

Comment: ok for further testing can you remove disabled and readonly attribute and see whether the values are getting set.I hope data has value in success callback

Comment: Neel it showing this warning in console [![Warning][2]][2]
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vqAAQ.jpg

Comment: you must be doing something else wrong.this warning has nothing to do what i suggested.I said only to remove readonly and disabled attributes mentioned in textbox for testing.

Comment: Yes i removed that and check it again still same problem. But before two  days this code and all working fine today only its not working..

Comment: in your question textbox has no id attribute.I dont know how this used to work previously.